# Conservation laws in Newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

1. Newton's third law is equivalent to conservation of momentum.
2. Assuming conservative systems, we get conservation of (mechanical) energy.
3. Assuming central forces, we get conservation of angular momentum.

**Questions:**

1. Second and third points above are just one way implications unlike the first point, right?
2. Is the conservation of momentum the *only* general conservation law (*i.e.* which applies to any force and initial conditions) if we just assume Newton's laws?

Comment: I think your second point should say "conservation of mechanical energy" because something slightly different is meant by conservation of energy

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient Yes I agree

Comment: I think the third point is a one way implication because I can imagine systems where some of the internal forces are not central but the torques produced by one pair of particles is cancelled by the torques produced by another pair of particles so that angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient +1. I agree.